# Regex: Allow multiple emails separated by ; (semicolon) AND allow blank/empty value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, validation

Here is my regex:

```
var emailsRegex = /^[\W]*([\w+\-.%]+@[\w\-.]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}[\W]*;{1}[\W]*)*([\w+\-.%]+@[\w\-.]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})[\W]*$/;
```

Currently it allows fully qualified single emails and multiple emails separated by semicolon, example:

```
email1@hi.com  
email1@hi.com; email2@hi.com
email1@hi.com; email2@hi.com; email3@hi.com
```

...are all valid.

I want this to stay the same, but also allow blank/empty inputs. My form is flagging $invalid with a blank input field, even though the `required` attribute is not specified on the input field.

I suspect this is because it is not passing the regex validation. Thanks!

Comment: try this /([^your regex ,]\/*/g

Comment: As an answer states, using a regex to verify email is fraught with danger. You should at most be checking to ensure that a `@` is present. After that, the only real way to verify the address is to send the email

Comment: I like the idea to check for `@` and `.` - and also allow empty - what's the regex for that? `/.+@.+\..+/i` works, but it still does not allow empty.

Answer (score 4):

[Please do not use a regex to match an email](https://davidcel.is/posts/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/). First of all your regex is wrong (it won't match emails like `foo+bar@example.org` which is perfectly valid given RFC822 and newer RFCs). You should better use a library like [verifyjs](http://verifyjs.jpillora.com/) or [fogcreek's email checker](https://github.com/FogCreek/email-addresses) to check that email.

Then all you have to do is to split your string around each emails using `email_string.split(';')` and apply the checker on each of them.

HTH

Comment: Thank you, I am reading your article suggestion right now and will come back soon to accept.

Comment: The article makes sense. However I don't really want to include another library just to check the email. I prefer their recommendation of just checking for `@` and `.` and call it valid. So how do I make this regex to allow empty OR anything with `@` and `.`? His recommendation of `/.+@.+\..+/i` does this check, but not allow empty.

Comment: oh, well you can try `/(.+@.+\..+)?/i` the `()` will group the full pattern, and `()?` will make it match `0` or `1` times the regex itself.

Answer (score -1):

I ended up using string.split(;) and then passing through an improved RegEx which should account for 99% of email addresses in use today. And I'm doing it inside an Angular Directive.

It allows for empty inputs, multiple emails separated by `;` which comply with the RFC for majority usage of email addresses.

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="emailCc" name="emailCc" ng-model="vm.ccRecipient" class="form-control input-sm" multiple-emails="vm.ccRecipient" placeholder="Email Cc" />
```

AngularJS

```
angular.module('my-app')
.directive('multipleEmails', function () {
  return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
          ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (rawInput) {

              var emails = rawInput.split(';');
              //console.log(emails);

              // Consider not using complex regex validation for emails. See: https://davidcel.is/posts/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/
              // Instead, consider just checking for an "@" and a "." and call it a done. The mail daemon will return whether its a valid or invalid/bounced email address
              //var emailsRegex = /.+@.+\..+/i;

              // define single email validator here
              var regexPattern = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

              // angular.foreach(emails, function() {
              var validityArr = emails.map(function (str) {
                  if (rawInput) {
                      return regexPattern.test(str.trim());

                  } else if (!rawInput) {
                      return true;
                  }
              }); // sample return is [true, true, true, false, false, false]

              //console.log(emails, validityArr);
              var atLeastOneInvalid = false;

              angular.forEach(validityArr, function (value) {
                  if (value === false)
                      atLeastOneInvalid = true;
              });

              if (!atLeastOneInvalid) {
                  // ^ all I need is to call the angular email checker here, I think.
                  ctrl.$setValidity('multipleEmails', true);
                  return rawInput;
              } else {
                  ctrl.$setValidity('multipleEmails', false);
                  return undefined;
              }

          });
      }
  };
});
```